cannot connect to pdb in oracle 21c with a regular user
Hi I've recently installed an oracle 21c on  Oracle linux 8.  and I havent't  been able to connect to PDB  with a regular(non sysdba user) to pdb . I've create a few users in pdb given them create session,connect rights and still no luck. oracle denies the connect with ora 01017 - invalid username or password
so here is my  relevant files
env
    ORACLE_UNQNAME=debugutf
    ORACLE_SID=debugutf
    ORACLE_BASE=/home/app/oracle
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
    DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
    ORACLE_HOME=/home/app/oracle/product/21.0.0/dbhome_1
    HOSTNAME=new_debug.ieml.ru
    PDB_NAME=PDB1
    DATA_DIR=/home/oradata
    S_COLORS=auto
    which_declare=declare -f
    CLASSPATH=/home/app/oracle/product/21.0.0/dbhome_1/jlib:/home/app/oracle/product/21.0.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/jlib
    USER=oracle
    PWD=/home/app/oracle/homes/OraDB21Home1/network/admin
    SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass
    HOME=/home/oracle
    TMP=/tmp
    XDG_DATA_DIRS=/home/oracle/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share
    NLS_LANG=RUSSIAN_RUSSIA.AL32UTF8
    TMPDIR=/tmp
    ORA_INVENTORY=/home/app/oraInventory
    MAIL=/var/spool/mail/oracle
    SHELL=/bin/bash
    TERM=linux
    SHLVL=1
    ORACLE_HOSTNAME=new_debug.ieml.ru
    LOGNAME=oracle
    ORACLE_PDB_SID=PDB1
    PATH=/home/app/oracle/product/21.0.0/dbhome_1/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/home/oracle/.local/bin:/home/oracle/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
    HISTSIZE=1000
    LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
    BASH_FUNC_which%%=() {  ( alias;
     eval ${which_declare} ) | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --read-functions --show-tilde --show-dot $@
    }
    _=/usr/bin/env
    OLDPWD=/home/oracle


[oracle@new_debug admin]$ cat listener.ora
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: /home/app/oracle/homes/OraDB21Home1/network/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.
  SID_LIST_LISTENER    =
 (SID_LIST =
 (SID_DESC =
 (GLOBAL_DBNAME = pdb1.ieml.ru)
 (ORACLE_HOME = /home/app/oracle/product/21.0.0/dbhome_1)
 (SID_NAME = PDB1 )
 )
 )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS_LIST=
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.117)(PORT = 1521))
      )
    )
  )

[oracle@new_debug admin]$ cat tnsnames.ora
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: /home/app/oracle/homes/OraDB21Home1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

DEBUGUTF.IEML.RU =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.117)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = debugutf.ieml.ru)
    )
  )


PDB1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.117)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = PDB1)
    )
  )


LISTENER =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.117)(PORT = 1521))

[oracle@new_debug admin]$ cat sqlnet.ora
# sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File: /home/app/oracle/homes/OraDB21Home1/network/admin/sqlnet.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT )

SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER = 8
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT = 8

[oracle@new_debug admin]$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.1.117 new_debug.ieml.ru ieml.ru

[oracle@new_debug admin]$ lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on 28-ИЮЛ-2024 16:26:11

Copyright (c) 1991, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Соединение с (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
СТАТУС ПРОСЛУШИВАТЕЛЯ
------------------
Псевдоним                LISTENER
Версия           TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Начальная Дата             28-ИЮЛ-2024 15:16:32
Время работы              0 дней 1 час. 9 мин. 39 сек
Уровень трассировки            off
Защита          ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Файл параметров прослушивателя   /home/app/oracle/homes/OraDB21Home1/network/admin/listener.ora
Журн.файл прослушивателя          /home/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/new_debug/listener/alert/log.xml
Сводка прослушивания конечных точек...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.1.117)(PORT=1521)))
Сводка служб...
Служба "1d65526d54d47c93e0637501a8c05507.ieml.ru" имеет 1 экземпл.
  Экземпляр "debugutf", состояние READY, имеет 2 указат. для данной службы...
Служба "pdb1.ieml.ru" имеет 1 экземпл.
  Экземпляр "debugutf", состояние READY, имеет 2 указат. для данной службы...
Команда выполнена успешно.
sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Вс Июл 28 16:27:39 2024
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Присоединен к:
Oracle Database 21c Enterprise Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0

SQL> show con_name

CON_NAME
------------------------------
PDB1

SQL> create user A3 IDENTIFIED BY A3;

Пользователь создан.

SQL> GRANT CONNECT,CREATE SESSION TO A3;

Привилегии предоставлены.
SQL> EXIT
Отсоединено от Oracle Database 21c Enterprise Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0
[oracle@new_debug admin]$ sqlplus /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Вс Июл 28 16:32:35 2024
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> connect
Введите имя пользователя: A3
Введите пароль:
ERROR:
ORA-01017: неверно имя пользователя/пароль; вход в систему запрещается

[oracle@new_debug admin]$ sqlplus / as sysdba;

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Вс Июл 28 16:35:23 2024
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Присоединен к:
Oracle Database 21c Enterprise Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0

SQL> show parameter local_listener

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
local_listener                       string      (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=1
                                                 92.168.1.117)(PORT=1521))
 show parameter password

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
remote_login_passwordfile            string      EXCLUSIVE

any ideas?


when you try to connect as A3 you forgot to specify the service name so it looks for A3 in the CDB.

no a3 is in pdb1  , but you are right in terms of service name i had to specify full  service_name  like this  CONNECT A3/A3@//localhost:1521/PDB1.IEML.RU
specifying just pdb1 without the domain part dint work

I'd exactly what I said when you don't specify the service name, ORACLE searchs for the specified user in the CDB where it's not defined.

Thanks to a comment by  @p3consulting it turned out to be a service name issue. I  had to specify full service name with domain.name for connection to be established.
CONNECT A3/A3@//192.168.1.117:1521/PDB1.IEML.RU

